# PUT Request : 406 Returned

Tags: java, apache, http, post, put

I'm trying to integrate Qiwi Payment gateway. I followed this API : https://ishop.qiwi.ru/docs/QIWI_Pull_API_v2.1_eng.pdf

```
URL url = new URL("https://w.qiwi.com/api/v2/prv/269946/bills/64785");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml,text/xml");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic MTIwNTQyOTU6a0ozYk1qYmRFd21lY1lHc0FTazg=");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,ms;q=0.6,es;q=0.4");

OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());              osw.write("user=tel%3A%2B29743543233&amount=766.90&ccy=AED&comment=PNR+%3A+33330521+User+Mobile+%3A+%2B29743543233&lifetime=2014-07-15T03%3A56%3A16&prv_name=Air+Arabia");
osw.flush();
osw.close();
System.err.println(connection.getResponseCode());
```

Above code always returns 406. I cannot figure out what is wrong.
Please Help me with this.

Thank You

Comment: Dunno whether that's the problem here, but "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" doesn't have a charset parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some thing wrong with the ordering of parameters. It was not the order that is mentioned in the API. 
I changed the order and now it is fine.

```
amount=100.03&ccy=USD&comment=PNR : 3333232522 User Mobile : +3762345234&lifetime=2014-07-16T04:39:57&user=tel%3A%2B79346433149&prv_name=Air Arabia
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Response code 406 indicates that the requested resource is not available in the format that you send as acceptable in the request. Try omitting the "Accept"-Properties and see, if you get a different response then.

You can also read about the 406 return code here: http://httpwg.github.io/specs/rfc7231.html#rfc.section.6.5.6

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I tried removing "Accept" but the response doesn't change.. 
I tried other stack-overflow questions and couldn't manage to solve the problem.

Comment: Please avoid citing obsolete specs; see http://httpwg.github.io/specs/rfc7231.html#rfc.section.6.5.6